# How can I get the value in Firebase Database with android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

My Firebase Realtime Database is like this :

```
{Singer :
    Billie Eilish :
        01 :
            songType : "type01"
            songName : "bad guy"
        02 :
            songType : "type02"
            songName : "bury a friend"
    Lauv :
        01 :
            songType : "type01"
            songName : "I Like Me Better"
        02 :
            songType : "type03"
            songName : "lonely"
    Anne Marie :
        01 :
            songType : "type02"
            songName : "2002"
        ...
        ...
        ...
}
```

If I want to get all the song that "type01", what should I do? This is my Adapter class that show the data in recyclerView in MainActivity.

Adapter class :

```
public class MyAdapter extends Recycler.Adapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@Nonnull ViewHolder holder, int i) {
        ...
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Singer");
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemModel>().setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<ItemModel>() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ItemModel parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.child("songType").getValue().toString().equals("type01") {
                    String song = snapshot.child("songName").getValue().toString();
                    return new ItemModel(song);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }).build();
        recyclerAdapter = new AnotherAdapter(options);
        recyclerAdapter.startListening();
}
```

I think it is weird in the query. It called only the child "Singer". I want to call all the child and get what songType is "type01". AnotherAdapter is just extending FirebaseReyclcerAdapter and just set the text in its AnotherViewHolder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but... there is no function ```getChildren()```...

Answer (score 3):

why don't you just go with fetch data which contains only **songType : type01** try this

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Query query = reference.child("Singer").orderByChild("songType").equalTo("type01");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot issue : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //set featched value to recyclerview 
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But there is a little problem... Your code [reference.child("SInger").orderByChild("songType").equalTo("type01")] can't read the data... Maybe each singer data has the number of sing list like 01, 02, 03 ...

Answer (score 2):

Since you're passing a reference to `Singers` into the recycler view, your `parseSnapshot` is called for each singer. In there you need to make sure you check the `songType` of each **`song`** child of the singer, where now you check the `songType` of the singers themselves (which never exists, so never goes into the `if` block).

So it'd be something like this:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Singer");
options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemModel>().setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<ItemModel>() {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemModel parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        String song = "No song found";
        for (DataSnapshot songSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String songType = songSnapshot.child("songType").getValue(String.class)
            if (songType.equals("type01") {
              song = songType;
              ...
```

I'm not sure though if this is what you want, because you seem to want a list of songs, while you're passing in a list of singers. The above will only work if each singer has exactly one song of `type01` (not 0, not more).

If that is not the case, the adapters in FirebaseUI won't fit your needs with your current data structure, since they show a **list** of items from the database, while you want to show items from a tree-like structure.

The two main options that come to mind in that case:

1. Build your own adapter, typically based on `ArrayAdapter` as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).
2. Change your data structure so that all songs are in a flat list (and the singer then becomes a property of each song).

Comment: Thank you for help! Um... Can I ask question?? What is the role ```isType``` boolean??

Comment: I cleaned up that code a bit. But seriously consider using a data structure that matches the needs of your UI. Since you want to show a list of artists with their type01 song, store in your database a list of artists with **just** their type01 song title.