# How can I get child value in Firebase database with android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055870/how-can-i-get-the-value-in-firebase-database-with-android/58056213#58056213), I asked to get the data in firebase. But I can't get the value... My database like this.

```
{Singer :
    {Eminem :
        {01 :
            songName : "Rap god",
            songType : "type01"
        },
        {02 :
            songName : "Till I collapse",
            songType : "type02"
        }
    },
    {Lauv :
        {01 :
            songName : "I Like Me Better",
            songType : "type01"
        },
        {02 :
            songName : "lonely",
            songType : "type03"
        }
    },
    {Alan Walker :
        {01 : 
            songName : "All Falls Down",
            songType : "type02"
        },
        {02 :
            songName : "On My Way",
            songType : "type01"
        }
    }  
}
```

I want to get all `type01` in `Singer` all of them. I tried code like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int i) {
    ...
    Query myQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Singer").orderByChlid("songType").equalsTo("type01");
    FirebaseRecyclerOption.Builder<ItemModel>.setQuery(myQuery, new SanpshotParser<ItemModel>() {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ItemModel parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String songStr = snapshot.child("songName").getValue().toString();
            String typeStr = snapshot.child("songType").getValue().toString();

            return new ItemModel(songStr, typeStr);
        }
    }).build();
    ...
}
```

But I can't get what I want. `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Singer").orderByChild("songType").equalsTo("type01")` can't read the data in function `parseSnapshot`. How can I get all the singer's songs that type is `type01`?

Comment: your trying to retrieve the child of child from above query. So it won't work as you expected. Even frank van puff explained in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43295289/10182897)

Comment: In my previous answer I gave you the two options: 1) build your own adapter, 2) change your data structure to a flat list of songs, so FirebaseUI can work with it. You seem to be doing neither here, which is the reason it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go one step deeper so the query can access `songType`:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Singer").child("Eminem").orderByChild("songType").equalsTo("type01")
```

Comment: I suggest to put recyclerview to retrieve the list of singer. Then get onClick of each singer name retrieve the type01 song

Comment: Me too good idea

Comment: There is only/at most one song with `type01` per singer it seems. So it could make sense to show *that* for each singer. It's just that the data structure OP uses isn't suitable for doing that FirebaseUI to do that, which is why I recommended a flat data structure in answer to their previous question.